# Implementing JS native 'filter' method with a function that takes two arguments

Tags: javascript, foreach, functional-programming

In a functional programming exercise I found online, the instructions are as follows:

"Implement JavaScript’s native ‘filter’ method that takes two arguments (a collection and a test function that returns either a ‘true’ or a ‘false’) and iterates over the collection using the ‘each’ function you wrote earlier and returns the resultant array."

I've already completed the first part of the exercise and created a function that implements JS' forEach method:

```
var each = function(collection, iterator) {
  if(Array.isArray(collection)){
   for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
  // value, key/property, collection
    iterator(collection[i],i,collection);
  }
  } else if (typeof collection === "object"){
    for(var property in collection){
      iterator(collection[property], property, collection);
    }

   }else{
     console.log("you messed up!");
  }
 };
```

Test my function with:

```
function returnOdds(currentEl) {
   return currentEl % 2 !== 0;
}
 console.log(filter([1, 2, 3], returnOdds)); // output: 1, 3
```

I'm not sure how to call my 'each' function on the 'collection' parameter inside my filter function.

Is this legal to do?

```
function filter(collection, test) {
   each(collection);

}
```

Or perhaps I can call the 'test' parameter as a function that checks to see if collection[i] is not an even/odd number?

```
function filter(collection, test) {
   var odd = function(each()){
    each(collection){
       if(collection[i] !== 0){
            return odd;
          }
         }
       }
    }
```

I am wondering if any of this even makes sense or can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter()` function that you are being asked to implement needs to somehow build up a new array of values that pass the test, and then return that new array. Here's one way to do it that uses your existing `each()` method:

```
var filter = function(collection, test) {
  var results = [];
  each(collection, function(val) {
    if (test(val)) {
      results.push(val);
    }
  });
  return results;
};
```

You can then call this function in the way you showed in the middle of your question, passing in an array and a reference to some other function that will return true or false for a given item:

```
var oddNumbers = filter([1, 2, 3], returnOdds);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4rj7phot/

So this works as follows:

1. Create an empty array for the results.
2. Use your `each()` function to execute an anonymous function for each item in the `collection` argument.
3. Within the anonymous function, call the function provided in the `test` argument, passing the current item value, and if that function returns true (or a truthy value) add the item to the `results` array.
4. Return the `results`.

I'll leave any validation of the arguments (e.g., checking that `test` actually is a function) to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still a bit confused on what the "val" argument does in the anon function. Particularly I don't quite understand what you mean by "call the function provided in the test() argument".

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a step back from the `filter()` implementation and just work on some simpler examples calling your own `each()` function by itself to do some simple array iteration. For example, trying using `each()` to print out all of the values in a given array. (Perhaps use `console.log()` to "print".)

Comment: Your `each()` takes two arguments, the first being the array that it will loop over, the second being a callback function that it will call for each element - when `each` calls that function it passes the value of the current item in the first argument: that's what the line `iterator(collection[i],i,collection);` does in your function. (It also passes some other arguments, but *my* code ignores them.) So in *my* code, the anonymous function is the `iterator()` being called, and `val` is the argument that receives the value of the current element.

Comment: All of this type of code relies on the fact that in JS functions are a type of object, and when you call function `a` you can pass a reference to function `b` as an argument such that function `a` can then call `b()`.